# Primefaces and complex visual selectOneMenu

Tags: java, primefaces

I want to create `selectOneMenu` component with panel like the showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) (the last list named "Content with Filter").

My goal is to show flags and associated locales.

My code is this one :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{locale.selectedLanguage}" var="selected">
    <f:selectItems value="#{locale.languages}" var="language" itemValue="#{language}"/>
        <p:column>
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/flags/flag_#{selected}.png" width="40" height="50" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>  
            #{selected}
        </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And my `locale` bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="locale")
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocaleBean.class);

private String locale;

private List<String> languages;

private String selectedLanguage;

public LocaleBean() {
    super();

    languages = new ArrayList<String>();
    languages.add("fr");
    languages.add("en");
}

public String getLocale() {             
    return locale;
}

public void setLocale(String locale) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(locale));      
    this.locale = locale;
}

public List<String> getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}

public void setLanguages(List<String> languages) {
    this.languages = languages;
}

public String getSelectedLanguage() {
    return selectedLanguage;
}

public void setSelectedLanguage(String selectedLanguage) {
    this.selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage;
}
```

}

With this code, my `selectOneMenu` contains `fr` and `en` values whereas I want flag image and locale.

When I set `itemLabel` attribute of `selectItems` tag to `foo` I have only `foo` values so it seems that my `p:column` are never used/read.

Where can be my error please ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the solution in primefaces forum.

Actually, when iterator is type of `String` columns render are not rendered.

So I have to create custom object and encapsulate my `String` inside it.

[Discussion here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27617&p=86780#p86780)